# JQgrid reordering columns and resizing the columns supported in touch screen enabled Pc's and mobile?

Tags: jqgrid

I searched in over a net that jqgrid supports columns ordering and resizing for touch screen but no information was available hence posting a question.

then i checked http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SortableColumns.htm in mobile for ordering the columns but it was not ordering columns how to order the columns and resize the columns through mobile.

Whether jqgrid supports ordering of columns and resizing the columns in touch screens and in mobiles ? if not how to support this features ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js or jquery.ui.touch-punch.js (https://github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch/) to your site

Please note that if you are using jQuery UI's components, Touch Punch must be included after jquery.ui.mouse.js, as Touch Punch modifies its behavior.

Comment: Once we use this touch punch.js is resizing and reordering of jqgrid will support in touch enable pc ?

Comment: it should, but please, emulate and check it

Comment: Thanks for answer ,its working after added touch punch but resizing with button has problem because i made jqgrid header as resizable but columns are not synchronized with header when resized pls help on this here is the code available in the path https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=13be3956f615d2b1&id=13BE3956F615D2B1%216242

Comment: you could modify your gridComplete method
gridComplete: function(){ 
 $(".ui-jqgrid th").click(function() {
  var colWidth;

  $(".ui-jqgrid th").each(function(i, el){
   colWidth = $(this).width() + "px";
   $("#list .jqgfirstrow td")[i].style.width = colWidth;
  });

});
},

it's the easiest way, but I believe that there is another more elegant method

Comment: thank u for reply but synchronisation is not happening in mobile device,in normal pc its working.

Comment: it because you watch for click, try to change it to something like touchend